# Standardizing only continuous variables using Scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a dataset like this

```
Total_Unique_items_bought   Total_Unique_Departments_visited    Total_qty_bought    Dept_Popular    Dept_Produce    Dept_D_n_E  Dept_Beverages  Dept_Pantry Dept_Frozen Dept_Deli   Dept_Bakery Dept_M_n_S  Dept_Household  Dept_Canned_Goods   Is_shopping_Monday  Is_shopping_Tuesday Is_shopping_Wednesday   Is_shopping_Thursday    Is_shopping_Friday  Is_shopping_Saturday    HrofDay_0_6 HrofDay_6_12    HrofDay_12_18   HrofDay_18_00   Is_store_id_3   Is_store_id_1   Is_store_id_5   Is_store_id_31  Is_store_id_29  Is_store_id_105 Is_store_id_115 Is_fulfillment_model_1  intercept
113818  26  10  36.0    1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1
62172   22  11  32.0    1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
116483  25  10  27.0    1   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1240    14  5   20.0    1   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
22087   20  7   33.0    1   1   1   1
```

Only the first three are continuous values. Rest are categorical (binary).

I changed the dtypes of rest to "category" as below

```
cols=['Dept_Popular', 'Dept_Produce', 'Dept_D_n_E',
       'Dept_Beverages', 'Dept_Pantry', 'Dept_Frozen', 'Dept_Deli',
       'Dept_Bakery', 'Dept_M_n_S', 'Dept_Household', 'Dept_Canned_Goods',
       'Is_shopping_Monday', 'Is_shopping_Tuesday',
       'Is_shopping_Wednesday', 'Is_shopping_Thursday',
       'Is_shopping_Friday', 'Is_shopping_Saturday', 'HrofDay_0_6',
       'HrofDay_6_12', 'HrofDay_12_18', 'HrofDay_18_00', 'Is_store_id_3',
       'Is_store_id_1', 'Is_store_id_5', 'Is_store_id_31',
       'Is_store_id_29', 'Is_store_id_105', 'Is_store_id_115',
       'Is_fulfillment_model_1', 'intercept']

for col in cols: 
    train_X[col]=train_X[col].astype('category')
```

Now  I want to standardize thee three variables such a way that I can use the same transformer API to standardize the test data with same standardizer. So for that I used Sklearn Standardizer

```
# Standardizing the features of the dataset
def standardize(train_X,test_X):
    """ This function takes the dataset and standardizes each feature

    """

    # Standardizing the data with zero mean and Unit standard deviation of each feature (columns)
    from sklearn import preprocessing

    # Getting the standardizing scaler to be used for any new data too
    scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(train_X)
    train_X_std=scaler.transform(train_X)

    ## Using the same transformation fitted on training data to transform the test data. 
    test_X_std=scaler.transform(test_X)

    return train_X_std,test_X_std,scaler
```

But this is also standardizing my categorical variables. How to prevent that.

Edit;

Using standard scaler variables

```
# Standardizing the features of the dataset
def standardize(train_X,test_X):
    """ This function takes the dataset and standardizes each feature

    """

    # Standardizing the data with zero mean and Unit standard deviation of each feature (columns)
    from sklearn import preprocessing

    # Getting the standardizing scaler to be used for any new data too
    cols=["Total_Unique_items_bought","Total_Unique_Departments_visited","Total_Qty_bought"]
    scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(train_X[cols])
    train_X_std=scaler.transform(train_X[cols])

    ## Using the same transformation fitted on training data to transform the test data. 
    test_X_std=scaler.transform(test_X[cols])
    return train_X_std,test_X_std,scaler
```

Comment: Only send those columns to standardScaler which you want to scale instead of whole X_train. Else if you want to use this in a complex setup (using pipelines) then see [FeatureUnion example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html) and/ or use sklearn-pandas.

Comment: sending those columns doesn't help. Have checked that. It standardizes whole test data

Comment: Can you add code how you are sending that. Please post complete code

Comment: @VivekKumar Pls see the edit

Comment: Yes, Now are you still getting your categorical data scaled?

Comment: @VivekKumar. Yes thats what I mentioned. When I write the above code and look at the resultant matrix first few rows, all the values are in decimals. While the original matrix doesn't have categorical variables in decimals.

Comment: See the `train_X_std` used on the numerical columsn will only return 3 columns, you then need to add those columns to your original `train_X` (replace the unscaled columns). Are you doing this? Or the `train_X_std` contains more than 3 cols. Please edit the question, and add actual output.